# Using blockUi.js Image not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using **jquery.blockUI.js**.

My worry is when search button clicked its not showing image, only shows message

> 'Please wait..'

My code is :

```
$('#<%= btn_search.ClientID%>').click(function () {
     $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="../images/ajax-loader.png" />  Please wait.. </h1>' });                
     });
```

Comment: *Thats* your *code*?!

Comment: When you say "not showing image" does it pop up with the standard "broken image" image? or is there no place for an image at all? Cause your code works in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5XBH/  (with minor changes)

Comment: yes. It popup with standard "broken image". I think it takes time to load image.

Comment: I have checked with JSFiddle. The problem remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. Then I Googled for an hour and found that it was like a bug in 'blockui.js' library. The work around I found was to load the image in a hidden div as follow -

```
<div style="display: none;"> 
    <img height="64" width="64" src="../images/ajax-loader.png" alt=""/> 
</div>
```